# REST uri to get data from community junction(CJ) fails

Tags: web-services, rest, affiliate, commission-junction, cj

I am making REST calls to download reports from commission junction(CJ) but not able to fetch data. Instead I am able to manually download report with the desired column as 
`Account name`,`Campaign name`,`Ad group`,`Destination URL`,`Ad distribution`,`Impressions`,`Clicks`,   `CTR`,`Average`,`CPC`,`Spend`,`Avg`. `position`.
The REST uri I am using is

```
https://commission-detail.api.cj.com/v3/commissions?date-type=posting&start-date=2013-03-14&end-date=2013-04-14&action-types=impression
```

Is this the right REST uri to get the data for desired columns mentioned above.Please suggest.

Comment: what error do you get? Do you specify a developer key?

Comment: Hi Michael,I am not getting any error but no. of records getting fetched from web service is 0 .It means I am getting response from there but no records are getting fetched . Please suggest how i can get the above specified columns's values .

Comment: And yes i have specified Developer's key too.Authentication is succeeded , response is coming with no resultset.

Comment: any luck with this? I am having the same issue, getting 0 records.

Comment: Try a simple query first - e.g. curl -H "authorization: apikey" https://commission-detail.api.cj.com/v3/commissions?date-type=event  does that work?

Answer (score 1):

I believe using v3 you can only get yesterdays data.

http://www.ericnagel.com/how-to-tips/commission-junction-web-services.html